# sierpinski carpet - area of a rectangle

Tags: c

I have no idea how to count the area of a rectangle in a [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) with recursion.

I know how to count empty rectangle in any level:

```
int sier(int level)
{
    if(level==1) return 1;
    else
    {
        return sier(level-1) + pow(8,level-1);
    }
}
```

But I really don't know how to count the area of a rectangle with non-empty rectangles.

I tried this: (a - side length)

```
double area(int level, int a)
{
    if(level == 1) return (1.0/9.0) * pow(a,2);
    else
    {
        return pole(level-1,a) * (1.0/pow(2,2*level));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think counting empty squares is a false trail.  The Sierpinski carpet has a recursive construction; it seems reasonable to model the area computation on the fractal's native recursion rule.  Count what's filled, not what's empty.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks! Was very helpful. I did it :)

Answer (score 1):

The formula for calulating the Sierpinski carpet is same as given in the Wikipedia Link. Let A be the area of the rectangle in a Sierpinski Carpet at Level 0.

```
double Sier(int level)
{
    return Math.Pow(double.Parse(8.0/9.0), (double)level) * A;
}
```

I hope this helps!